# OpenWrt: Cannot install package sudo

Tags: linux, installation, sudo, package-management, openwrt

I have installed the latest `OpenWrt Chaos Calmer r42871` on my `TP-LINK WR-842ND` router. And everything's good except the problem:

> root@router:~# opkg install sudo
>
> Unknown package 'sudo'.
>
> Collected errors:
>
> - opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package sudo.

In the same time I **can** install another packages like: `shadow-useradd`, `shadow-groupadd`, etc.

The target idea is to disable the `root` user and [to make a router more secure](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/secure.access) by using non-priv user by default (I suppose `sudo` would help with it at least).

It's really strange that Mr. Google doesn't know about this error yet. But I hope it will already. :)

Any advices needed!

Comment: If you don’t need bleeding edge code, I suggest you stick to Barrier Breaker.

Comment: Is it possible to rollback to BB?

Comment: I don’t know. Probably not, but you should be able to keep most of the config files.

Comment: Considering that routers are usually only accessed by their administrators, they typically use just the root account, and can happen that the sudo package is not even compiled for those platforms.  First try to find if it is available in the repositories.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the list of packages:

```
opkg update
```

Then try to showing the info for the package you are interested in:

```
opkg info sudo
```

More information in the [online documentation of the project](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/opkg).

Comment: It doesn't work. See the error on my question...

Comment: How to check if the package exists in the repository? Or where could I report about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

`sudo` is not provided anymore by this distribution, and the `sudo` paragraph from this documentation seems outdated.

As you can see in this `ps -w` exctract from my router, almost all processes are running as root :

```
  (... kernel process edited out)
  832 root      8984 S    /sbin/ubusd
  833 root      2716 S    /sbin/askfirst /usr/libexec/login.sh
  834 root      2716 S    /sbin/askfirst /usr/libexec/login.sh
 1122 root      7040 S    /sbin/logd -S 64
 1123 root     11120 S    /sbin/logread -f -h router -r 10.13.9.40 514 -p /var/run/logread.2.pid
 1132 root     15296 S    /sbin/rpcd
 1167 root     15440 S    /sbin/netifd
 1307 root      2888 S    /usr/sbin/dropbear -F -P /var/run/dropbear.1.pid -p 10.13.9.1:22 -K 300
 1846 root     24228 S    /usr/sbin/uhttpd -f -h /www -r router -x /cgi-bin -u /ubus -t 60 -T 30 -k 20 -A 1 -n 3 -N 100 -R -p 0.0.0
 1859 zabbix    5420 S    /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd -c /etc/zabbix_agentd.conf -f
 1866 zabbix    5420 S    /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: collector [idle 1 sec]
 1867 zabbix    5420 S    /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: listener #1 [waiting for connection]
 1868 zabbix    5428 S    /usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd: active checks #1 [idle 1 sec]
 1876 root     15036 R    /usr/sbin/openvpn --syslog openvpn(server) --status /var/run/openvpn.server.status --cd /var/etc --config
 1908 root      3060 S <  /usr/sbin/ntpd -n -N -l -S /usr/sbin/ntpd-hotplug -p ***EDITED_OUT***.org -p ***EDITED_OUT***.org -p ***EDITED_OUT***
 1960 dnsmasq   2968 S    /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -C /var/etc/dnsmasq.conf -k -x /var/run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid
 2688 root      3336 S    {dynamic_dns_upd} /bin/sh /usr/lib/ddns/dynamic_dns_updater.sh -v 0 -S ***EDITED_OUT*** -- start
 2689 root      3336 S    {dynamic_dns_upd} /bin/sh /usr/lib/ddns/dynamic_dns_updater.sh -v 0 -S ***EDITED_OUT*** -- start
 2690 root      3340 S    {dynamic_dns_upd} /bin/sh /usr/lib/ddns/dynamic_dns_updater.sh -v 0 -S ***EDITED_OUT*** -- start
 8532 root      3000 R    /usr/sbin/dropbear -F -P /var/run/dropbear.1.pid -p 10.13.9.1:22 -K 300
 8533 root      3064 S    -ash
 8609 root      3056 S    sleep 600
 8616 root      3056 S    sleep 600
 8620 root         0 SW   [kworker/u8:1]
 8678 root      3056 S    sleep 600
 8691 root      3056 R    ps w
```

So by adding the `sudo` packages, adding a user, and after a lot of configuration, the only security you will gain is typing `sudo` before every command, or `sudo -i` after each login.

According to Raúl Salinas-Monteagudo's comment, this distribution is intended for router machines, only accessed by their administrators.